# What is the class for min width using Bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I looked at the documentation for Bootstrap 5 but I can't seem to find the min-width class using pixels? Is there any?

https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: There is no such class. You'll have use custom CSS to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Bootstrap CSS Grid layout does the heavy lifting in terms of setting responsive breakpoints.
- Each view/page/front-end element can be divided into 12 parts. and you can choose how much space a container takes out of 12 vertical columns.
- Bootstrap 5 gives you 6 breakpoints pre-defined, with the following syntax

```
    col-xs-{number-between-1-to-12}  width <= 540px
    col-sm-{number-between-1-to-12}  max-width = 540px
    col-md-{number-between-1-to-12}  max-width = 720px
    col-lg-{number-between-1-to-12}  max-width = 960px
    col-xl-{number-between-1-to-12}  max-width = 1140px
    col-xxl-{number-between-1-to-12} width <= 1400px
```

Example 1: You get a parent div with 2 child divs, these children will take equal divided space inside for all screen sizes

```
<div id="i-am-a-parent-div"> 
    
   <div class="col-6"> This takes First Half the Space inside parent element</div>

   <div class="col-6"> This takes Second Half the Space inside parent element</div>

</div>
```

Example 2: The Children divs will share 6/12 space each till max-width=540, but then they will change space occupation to 4/12 and 8/12 respectively.
NOTE: I've added two separated classes for each child div, you can add as many as needed for each breakpoint.

```
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> This takes First Half (6/12) the Space inside parent element till max-width = 540px,
      BUT it will only take One-Thirds (4/12) the space between 540px & 768px </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8"> This takes Second Half (6/12) the Space inside parent element till max-width = 540px,
      BUT it will only take Two-Thirds (8/12) the space between 540px & 768px </div>
</div>
```

If this doesnt satisfy what you need to do, Then there are more customization options to their breakpoints, Feel free to checkout: https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

Let me know if this helps you out!